# Conditional operators in C

Tags: c

If the following code works

```
i=1;
i<10 ? printf("Hello") : printf("Bye");
```

then the assignment should also work.What is the reason which makes it to produce error?

```
i<10 ? foo=10 : foo=12;
```

Comment: And why write such code?

Comment: @EdHeal : Though no practical use,just playing with C

Answer (score 6):

> What is the reason which makes it to produce error?

Operator precedence.

`i<10 ? foo=10 : foo=12;` is equivalent to `(i<10 ? foo=10 : foo) = 12;`

Use parentheses to fix your issue:

```
i<10 ? (foo=10) : (foo=12);
```

Comment: Also: `foo = i < 10 ? 10 : 12;`

Comment: @NemanjaBoric - And it is also more readable

Comment: @EdHeal more readable for me would be to use a `if` statement here.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what the Standard says here (maybe because I'm coming from C++): C99 6.5.15 says a *conditional-expression* is either a *logical-OR-expression* or a *logical-OR-expression* `?` *expression* `:` *conditional-expression*. So, while the first one can be an *assignment-expression*, I don't think the second one can be. C++ OTOH has a different (grammatical) definition, where the expression after the colon is an *assignment-expression*.

Comment: Oh, nevermind. `(` *expression* `)` is a *primary-expression* and therefore a *logical-OR-expression*. (This probably means that `i<10 ? foo=10 : (foo=12);` is legal, too.)

Answer (score 3):

The reason is operator precedence. The following will work:

```
i<10 ? (foo=10) : (foo=12);
```

Your original expression gets parsed as

```
(i<10 ? foo=10 : foo)=12;
```

giving rise to the error (`lvalue required as left operand of assignment`).